# What is the best way to access and organize this list of uneven lists in a way that I could use for a relational SQL database?

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, relational-database

I have this beer dataset that I've been trying to clean as a personal project for quite some time, but I can't seem to get past a couple of hiccups.

I have this "list of uneven lists" I guess you would call it, that I need to organize. Here is a brief example of what I'm looking at:
**[updated to add form of data]**

```
data = [[2.3810000000000002, 'American - Pale 2-Row', 37.0, 1.8, 44.7], [0.907, 'American - White Wheat', 40.0, 2.8, 17.0], [0.907, 'American - Pale 6-Row', 35.0, 1.8, 17.0], [0.227, 'Flaked Corn', 40.0, 0.5, 4.3], [0.227, 'American - Caramel / Crystal 20L', 35.0, 20.0, 4.3], [0.227, 'American - Carapils (Dextrine Malt)', 33.0, 1.8, 4.3], [0.113, 'Flaked Barley', 32.0, 2.2, 2.1], [0.34, 'Honey', 42.0, 2.0, 6.4]],[[2.722, 'Dry Malt Extract - Extra Light', 42.0, 2.5, 70.6],[[2.722, 'Liquid Malt Extract - Light', 35.0, 4.0, 59.1], [1.429, 'Liquid Malt Extract - Amber', 35.0, 10.0, 31.0]]]
```

So for column 0, which would relate to a beer called Vanilla Cream Ale, is a list of multiple lists that contain 5 parameters.

```
[[2.3810000000000002, 'American - Pale 2-Row', 37.0, 1.8, 44.7], [0.907, 'American - White Wheat', 40.0, 2.8, 17.0], [0.907, 'American - Pale 6-Row', 35.0, 1.8, 17.0], [0.227, 'Flaked Corn', 40.0, 0.5, 4.3], [0.227, 'American - Caramel / Crystal 20L', 35.0, 20.0, 4.3], [0.227, 'American - Carapils (Dextrine Malt)', 33.0, 1.8, 4.3], [0.113, 'Flaked Barley', 32.0, 2.2, 2.1], [0.34, 'Honey', 42.0, 2.0, 6.4]]
```

For column 1 I have

```
[[2.722, 'Dry Malt Extract - Extra Light', 42.0, 2.5, 70.6]]
```

2 is

```
[[2.722, 'Liquid Malt Extract - Light', 35.0, 4.0, 59.1], [1.429, 'Liquid Malt Extract - Amber', 35.0, 10.0, 31.0]]
```

Where each element is each element is 'weight', 'grain_name', 'ppg', 'deg_litner', 'grain_bill'.
So far, I have been able to separate out the weights, grain names, etc out of the lists into individual lists that I can call.

I'd like to end up having an ID, where 0 corresponds to Vanilla Cream ale with each of these elements being listed. I imagine '0' would be repeated eight times, '1' one times, and '2' two times, but I'm not sure that is the best approach.

I've managed to make a list that counted the number of lists in each element:

```
fcount = [8,1,2]
```

I was thinking I could do something like

```
for i in range(0,3):
    [i] * fcount
```

thinking I could get

```
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
[1]
[2,2]
```

but you apparently can't multiply a list like that.

I'm having a really hard time finding the best approach overall, and I'm not sure this is the right way - but it's SOME way, I suppose.
My overall goal is to complete a relational database in SQL Server - I have all the beer data in there (ibu, abv, etc), it's just missing this mess!
Thanks for any help with this!

Comment: The term you are looking for is "jagged array". You wouldn't store it in a database like that, you need to get it into rows and columns (and possibly normalize it into different tables)

Comment: Thank you! I had no idea what to call it. Now I know :)

Comment: What is the best way to get it into rows and columns? That's probably my real issue.

Comment: I guess I'm not clear on what you want. For the data you provided in the variable, `data`, what is your end goal? Is it `[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], [1], [2,2]` or something else? You may want to look into the pandas `explode` function, which can be used to pivot the value from each list into a separate row

Comment: I want those to be my ID's that correspond to my beer name ID's. Though, I'd rather it be generated automatically by organizing the list of lists correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution if I'm understanding correctly. Given the following input data

```
data = [[
        [2.3810000000000002, 'American - Pale 2-Row', 37.0, 1.8, 44.7],
        [0.907, 'American - White Wheat', 40.0, 2.8, 17.0],
        [0.907, 'American - Pale 6-Row', 35.0, 1.8, 17.0],
        [0.227, 'Flaked Corn', 40.0, 0.5, 4.3],
        [0.227, 'American - Caramel / Crystal 20L', 35.0, 20.0, 4.3],
        [0.227, 'American - Carapils (Dextrine Malt)', 33.0, 1.8, 4.3],
        [0.113, 'Flaked Barley', 32.0, 2.2, 2.1],
        [0.34, 'Honey', 42.0, 2.0, 6.4]
    ],
    [
        [2.722, 'Dry Malt Extract - Extra Light', 42.0, 2.5, 70.6]
    ],
    [
        [2.722, 'Liquid Malt Extract - Light', 35.0, 4.0, 59.1],
        [1.429, 'Liquid Malt Extract - Amber', 35.0, 10.0, 31.0]
    ]
]
```

loop through the outer most list and get the index of each element using `enumerate`. Then, loop through each inner list, prepend the index to each of the 5 element lists and combine them into one main list, `data_id`, and finally convert the main list into a dataframe that can be written to the database, as described in @David Browne - Microsoft's answer:

```
import pandas as pd
data_id = []
for ind, d in enumerate(data):
    for a in d:
        a.insert(0, ind)
        data_id.append(a)
df = pd.DataFrame(data_id)
df.columns = ['ID', 'Weight', 'GrainName', 'PPG', 'DegLitner', 'GrainBill']
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Hell yes! Thank you!

Comment: Just confirming that this worked perfectly. Can't thank you enough!

Answer (score 0):

What you refer to as a "uneven lists" is a "tuple" or a "row".  And a set of tuples/rows with the same shape is called a "relation" or a "table".

> Where each element is each element is 'weight', 'grain_name', 'ppg', 'deg_litner', 'grain_bill'

In SQL Server you would create tables like

```
create table Beers
(
  BeerId int identity primary key,
  BeerName varchar(200),
  ABV decimal(2,2)
)
create table BeerIngredients
(
  BeerId int not null referencess Beer(BeerId),
  BeerIngredientId int identity not null, 
  Weight decimal(10,2),
  GrainName varchar(200),
  PPG decimal(10,2),
  DegLitner decimal(10,2),
  GrainBill decimal(10,2),
  constraint pk_BeerIngredients 
    primary key (BeerName,BeerIngredientId)
)
```

And which you could load into a pandas table to work with in Python, something like this:

```
import pandas
import pyodbc
import sqlalchemy 

data = [[2.3810000000000002, 'American - Pale 2-Row', 37.0, 1.8, 44.7], 
        [0.907, 'American - White Wheat', 40.0, 2.8, 17.0], 
        [0.907, 'American - Pale 6-Row', 35.0, 1.8, 17.0], 
        [0.227, 'Flaked Corn', 40.0, 0.5, 4.3], 
        [0.227, 'American - Caramel / Crystal 20L', 35.0, 20.0, 4.3],
        [0.227, 'American - Carapils (Dextrine Malt)', 33.0, 1.8, 4.3], 
        [0.113, 'Flaked Barley', 32.0, 2.2, 2.1], 
        [0.34, 'Honey', 42.0, 2.0, 6.4],
        [2.722, 'Dry Malt Extract - Extra Light', 42.0, 2.5, 70.6]]


df = pandas.DataFrame(data, columns=['Weight','GrainName','PPG','DegLitner','GrainBill'])
print(df)
    
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://localhost/tempdb?trusted_connection=yes&driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server')
df.to_sql('BeerIngredients',engine, index=False,if_exists='replace')
```

Comment: I have the tables created in mssql already. I'm not sure how to organize my tuples/rows pythonically in order to insert the data into the the SQL table "BeerIngredients" in your example.

Comment: Easiest way is to create a pandas table that matches the SQL Server table.

Comment: Can you give an example with the data I gave?

Comment: See updated answer.

Comment: The data does not look like that. Try with data = [[2.3810000000000002, 'American - Pale 2-Row', 37.0, 1.8, 44.7], [0.907, 'American - White Wheat', 40.0, 2.8, 17.0], [0.907, 'American - Pale 6-Row', 35.0, 1.8, 17.0], [0.227, 'Flaked Corn', 40.0, 0.5, 4.3], [0.227, 'American - Caramel / Crystal 20L', 35.0, 20.0, 4.3], [0.227, 'American - Carapils (Dextrine Malt)', 33.0, 1.8, 4.3], [0.113, 'Flaked Barley', 32.0, 2.2, 2.1], [0.34, 'Honey', 42.0, 2.0, 6.4]],[[2.722, 'Dry Malt Extract - Extra Light', 42.0, 2.5, 70.6]]

Comment: Also, thank you very much for trying to help with this. I really appreciate it.

Comment: See update.  Isn't this `42.0, 2.0, 6.4]],[[2.722, 'Dry Malt Extract - Extra Light'` just a typo?

Comment: There was a typo, but not there. Forgot to add an ending bracket. The ]],[[ is intentional and copy and pasting from my question should you show you how the data looks and why your example doesn't work for this.

Comment: Well I’d say your data is messed up.  And will need to be transformed into a set of rows to make sense on a database.

Comment: Yes! Exactly! How do I do that?? Or better yet, what's a better way to ask how to do that on SO?